# AS3 ExternaInterface: Call a javascript function in a pop-up window invoked by Flash

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

In Flash, I have invoked a pop-up window using

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.open","http://www.mypage.com,"win","height=640,width=480,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes");
```

In the invoked pop-up, there is a javascript function I want to access. If the javascript were in the same page as the movie, I could use

```
ExternalInterface.call("jsFunction", "value")
```

Since it's not, how can I access the javascript functions in the pop-up window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to store a reference to the window that you opened to be able to access it. If you control the HTML/Javascript of the main main, you could insert something like this into the `<script>` block:

```
var popupref;
```

and window opening function:

```
function openWindow() {
    popupref = window.open(/*your params here*/)
}
```

and then in your `ExternalInterface` to open your window

```
ExternalInterface.call("openWindow");
```

and to call your popup window

```
ExternalInterface.call("popupref.myfunc");
```

I don't know off the top of my head, but you could potentially be able to make the `ExternalInterface.call(...)` by embedding the the whole `popupref = window.open(...)` call in it.

Be aware thought that the window that you opened has to come from the same domain and port otherwise the cross-domain browser security will not let you make the calls.

Comment: Passing "window.open" to ExternalInterface.call() works but I will be unable to pass my own data to the popup